# How to get number of connections for Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection

Before dropping a database on an Azure Sql Server I have to check if another user is connected to that db.

Using the stored procedure `sp_who2` fails with: 
`"Could not find stored procedure 'sp_who2'."`

Trying to get informations from `sys.sysprocesses` also fails with message:

```
"Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.sysprocesses' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."
```

How do I get the info I need?

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling found that [this approach](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dmv-queries/a-better-sp_who2-using-dmvs-sp_who3/) works quite well in SQL Azure. However it works only in the contexts of a concrete database! Remember that in SQL Azure you can only work with single DB at a time. If you need data from more than one DB you have execute the statement for each DB separately.

Side note, I could not get sp_who working in SQL Azure.

**EDIT**

The following is screenshot provided for evidence:
[image]

Comment: This approach does not work well, because it just shows the connection executing the stored procedure, not any other open connection from another computer or process currently fetching data.

Comment: When I say "works quite well" I mean it. I tested it against my production DB and it showed **all the connections from my worker roles also**, not only the connection that executes it!

Pay attention to the fact that it only works in the context of signle DB! If you are executing it in the Master DB, I do not expect to see any other processes in there!

Comment: Sorry, but sp_who3 returns just 1 row with the current db name (not "Master") in column "DBName" for which I want to fetch the info. Column "Host" contains the name of the computer, running the SQL Server Management Studio. Other clients, currently accessing the db are not shown.

Comment: are you running it with NULL (without) parameter ?

Comment: And does the user you run it under, have the necessary permissions to see other sessions? I run it with my admin user.

Comment: My Management Studio looks like yours. But only 1 row is returned when calling sp_who3.

Comment: And are you sure there are other connections to that specific database then? Because we seem to be circulating around "it works for me", "but not for me". So, are you 100% sure there are other processes that are running in your same Azure DB in which you are executing this procedure? If so, then this shall be a very strange unexplainable behaviour.

Comment: When I say "This approach does not work well" I mean it. :-) 
Yes I am 100% sure that I work on the same DB with two different processes on different maschines. In you screenshot you call a procedure called "up_who3". Is this the procedure of the linked approach, just renamed?

Comment: This works for me too. I can see connections from all sessions, not just the session executing the proc.